# Connect to private Amazon RDS without EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I see a lot of articles online where EC2 is involved, but since my backend is essentially serverless I have not found much information how to access my RDS once it is turned private. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Current state:

- Public MySQL RDS
- RDS is accessed by a MySQL client on my local machine (MySQL Workbench) and AWS Lambda functions via my web application (both connecting via SSL)

Future state:

- Private MySQL RDS
- Private RDS would continue to be accessed by *only* my local machine and *only* the noted AWS Lambda functions via my web application (I assume continuing to use SSL?)

Comment: FYI, it is generally a bad idea to separate a database from the 'compute'. Having a database in AWS and your compute on the Internet introduces a lot of latency that will impact the performance of your application. It's fine if you're just doing ad-hoc queries, but not a good idea if the main app is separated across the Internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your scenario your Lambda functions will need to be configured to run in the VPC if they are not already. That is the only change required for the Lambda functions.

However, When you switch the RDS instance to private, that means it only accepts connections from within the VPC. So you can't make connections directly from your local computer to the database anymore. You have to go through some sort of "bridge" to get your local computer into the AWS VPC network.

In this scenario people either use an EC2 instance as a [bastion host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host), or they create a VPN connection from their local computer into the AWS VPC. [AWS Client VPN](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/) is a managed service you could used for this.

You'll need to evaluate the Client VPN pricing, but I think you may find that a single `t4g.nano` EC2 bastion host is probably cheaper, and you can also stop the instance when you don't need it to really cut down the cost.

Comment: The only thing that I would add to @Mark's answer is that there is a third option called AWS Systems Manager Session Manager which supports port fowarding and could be used to proxy the local connections instead of the bastion host: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/

Comment: @Nick As far as I understand, Systems Manager Session Manager has to have an EC2 instance running the System Manager agent on it. In other words you would use SSM session manager instead of SSH, but you would still use an EC2 bastion host. I don't think it can forward a port directly to an RDS instance can it?

Comment: Yeah that's totally correct, it's usually "marketed" as a bastion host replacement, but in the RDS case it would need an EC2 instance with an agent running on it. So you are right, we will still need a jump server. The only thing Session Manager would add I this case would be better accountability as it has various options to log a lot of evidence on who did what .

Comment: @MarkB If I understand I properly:

To access the private RDS via my local machine: create the EC2 bastion host, put the EC2 in the same VPC as the RDS, and connect to the bastion host via my local machine to access the RDS. To access the private RDS via my Lambda functions, I need to put the Lambda in the same VPC as the RDS.

However, with the Lambda function using my own VPC, I would need to give internet access to the Lambda function, correct? Are there reasons why I would not need to grant internet access? These Lambda functions utilize various Javascript SDKs (aws-sdk, stripe, etc.).

Comment: You will need to give your Lambda functions Internet access if they are accessing things like Stripe. Unfortunately that means you will have to add a NAT Gateway to the VPC, as Lambda functions in a VPC will never have a public IP address directly assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VPC also with Lambda. Lambda and RDS can be in the same VPC, or in separate VPC’s peered together. Aws documentation for this scenario can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-lambda-to-an-rds-instance/

Comment: This doesn't address the question about connecting a local (non AWS) computer to a private RDS server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Basti](https://github.com/BohdanPetryshyn/basti), which is a CLI tool that manages the EC2 bastion instance for you. The tool keeps the instance stopped when it's not used to minimize the solution cost, performs software updates to maintain the bastion instance secure, and provides a convenient CLI that can be used locally and in CI/CD pipelines.